# forecasting daily data using tbats model

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have a daily time series about the sales of a product, my series start from 01/01/2016 until 30/09/2017.

There is something important about it. First, there is no data for Sundays because this shop doesn't work on Sundays (so, the expected value for Sundays is zero)  and second, there are multiple cyclic patterns (daily and weekly patterns).

For example, the best day of the week to sell is Tuesday, and the worst is Thursday. I know that tbats model is designed for use when there are multiple cyclic patterns, so I am using this model.

My problem is that I am getting an error message when forecasting:

```
Error in try.xts(0) : 
  Error in as.xts.double(x, ..., .RECLASS = TRUE) :   
    order.by must be either 'names()' or otherwise specified.
```

Here is my code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(xts)
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

milk <- read.table("Series.txt", header = TRUE)
attach(milk)
df$Date = mdy(df$Date)

# Now I remove Sundays

ts_no_sunday = df %>%
filter(wday(df$Date) != 1) %>%
  {xts(.$Units, .$Date)}
```

And finally, my tbats model

```
m_tbats = tbats(ts_no_sunday)
f_tbats = forecast(m_tbats, h=30)
```

And here is where I get this error:

```
Error in try.xts(0) : 
  Error in as.xts.double(x, ..., .RECLASS = TRUE) :
    order.by must be either 'names()' or otherwise specified
```

What am I doing wrong here ??

Thank you so much !

Pdt: Here is my data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIf8XvzKOGWMWFPcllhYnR5VDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code example doesn't define `df`. Is that the same as `milk`? Also, most people recommend not to use `attach`, it causes problems.

Comment: `forecast::tbats` asks for the data to be passed in as a `numeric`, `ts`, or `msts` object; `xts` is not mentioned in the documentation, and may cause issues. This makes sense when, for example, a model is implemented only for equally-spaced observations, and `xts` would allow arbitrarily-spaced observations. `tbats` also needs to know what frequency to use for seasonality, and `xts` objects don't always have one (since it can be irregular).